# Python: assign a pandas data frame a new index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame with 41 rows. It has an index series. How may I rename the index as -20, -19, -18, ...-1, 0, 1, ... 20? Thanks!!

```
df
Out[102]: 
                   ABC         DEF  ...         TUV         WXY
2011-01-03         NaN         NaN  ...         NaN         NaN
2011-01-04         NaN         NaN  ...         NaN         NaN
2011-01-05         NaN         NaN  ...         NaN         NaN
2011-01-06         NaN         NaN  ...         NaN         NaN
2011-01-07         NaN         NaN  ...         NaN         NaN
......
2011-02-22         NaN         NaN  ...         NaN         NaN
2011-02-23         NaN         NaN  ...         NaN         NaN
2011-02-24         NaN         NaN  ...         NaN         NaN
2011-02-25         NaN         NaN  ...         NaN         NaN
2011-02-28         NaN         NaN  ...         NaN         NaN

[41 rows x 15 columns]
```

Comment: df.index=[.....]

Comment: what the logic to generate the new index? One way is to generate that numbers into a separate column and then do `reset_index()` and then `set_index(column_name)` where column_name is a column having the values for new index i.e -20, -19..  so on

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
new_inex = list(range(-20,21))


df = df.reindex(new_inex)
```

Comment: Thanks. What can I do if I would like to make the middle three index be "a", "b", "c"? ```new_index = list(range(-20, -1), "a", "b", "c", range(2,21))``` It does not seem to work

Comment: ```list(range(-20, -1) )+ ['a', 'b', 'c'] +  list(range(2,21))```